# Solve Linear Equation to Tridiagonal Matrix?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, tridiagonal-matrices

I have 6 linear equation
$$
0= -F_1\cos30 + F_3\cos60 + F_{ 1, h} \\
0= -F_1\sin30 + F_3\sin60 + F_{ 1, v} \\
0= F_2\cos30 + F_1 3\cos30 + F_{ 2,h)} \\
0= F_1\sin30 + F_(2,v)+ V_2\\
0= -F_2 -F_3\cos 60 + F_{(3,h})\\
0= F_3\sin 60 + f_(3,v) + V_3\\ 
$$
my homework is required solve this equation by using tridiagonal matrix method by numerical method. i have been so confused, how to convert common matrix equation to tridiagonal form.
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0.866 & 0 & -0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0.5 & 0 & 0.866 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -0.866 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        -0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -0.866 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} 
       \begin{Bmatrix}
       F_1\\
       F_2\\
       F_3\\
       H_2\\
       V_2\\
       V_3\\
       \end{Bmatrix}
       =\begin{Bmatrix}0\\-1000\\0\\0\\0\\0 \end{Bmatrix}
$$

If the matrix already in the form tridiagonal I've been able to finish. and I am was confused on how to convert into tridiagonal form matrix

Any idea what the name of method to convert as tridiagonal form? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Please consider [using MathJax for typing the equations](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of posting some screenshots.

Comment: Sorry i've been updated..

Comment: Take a look at this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method Although it  may look confusing, but I think the examples have clarified the method

Comment: Is Gauss seidel to solve matrix directly? Because of my homework it need tridiagonal like Thomas Algorithm. 
But the Thomas Algorithm needs the matrix that already in tridiagonal form.
Thanks

Comment: Gauss-Siedel is for converting the matrix to what you say, tridiagonal form. Then you can do the rest

Comment: @polfosol Gauss-Sedel has nothing to do with tridiagonal matrices

Comment: Please add some details on how did you obtain the system. Why are some variables named like $F_i$ and others like $F_{i,h}, F_{i,v}$?

Comment: @uranix You are partly right. The same _idea_ could be used.

Comment: @polfosol [Tridiagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix) implies some structure which allows *direct* [Gaussian elimination algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm) to be very fast. Proposed [Gauss-Seidel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method) method is completely different *iterational* method. Anyway I don't see any benefit from TDMA for case with six unknows

Comment: @uranix Me neither

Comment: @uranix The problem appear from this picture (truss force): https://snag.gy/JpIFbz.jpg